# What is the length and number of the parts of a conformational epitope?

Tags: immune-system, protein-structure

I am interested in the question whether exposure to protein A might create antibodies that also bind to protein B.

I am wondering whether, if the antigen of protein A is a conformational epitope, it would still be possible to predict (or at least guess at) the reaction against protein B with only a sequence comparison.

This might be possible if the subunits are long enough and if there are enough of them, which is why I ask about their length and number.

Comment: You seem to be using the word "subunit" in a manner that conflicts with that used with respect to protein structure. Do you mean short stretches of primary structure that contribute to the epitope?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what I mean. I took that term from the definition of conformational epitope at wikipedia: "A conformational epitope is a sequence of sub-units (usually amino acids) composing an antigen that come in direct contact with a receptor of the immune system."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this paper](http://www.jimmunol.org/content/jimmunol/early/2013/06/22/jimmunol.1203198.full.pdf) that analyzes 111 antigen-antibody x-ray crystal structures.

They find that in their dataset that *"the large majority of Ag structures (86.5%) have CRS ranging from 20 to 229 aa."* CRS stands for contact regions span which they define as *"the minimum contiguous amino acid sequence containing all CRs of an Ag or Ab and represents the size of a complete structural epitope or paratope, inclusive of CR and the minimum set of supporting residues required for proper conformation."* further on they mention that *"The average and median CRS of all 111 Ag structures is 125 and 95 aa, respectively."* and "*the majority of the structures do indeed have epitope CRs that are clustered together in short, contiguous stretches ranging from 2 to 12 aa, longest contiguous sequence of CR being 5"*

I hope this helps.